# Two PDE for one matrix-valued unknown?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, linear-pde

Let $x \in (0,L)$, $t \in (0,T)$, and let $P = P(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$, $Q = Q(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$, $R_0 = R_0(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ and $G= G(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ be continuous functions.

My question is:

> Can we find a function $R = R(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ that satisfies
>   \begin{equation} 
> \begin{cases}
> \partial_t R(x,t) = R(x,t) P(x,t) & \text{in } (0,L)\times(0,T)\\
> \partial_x R(x,t) = R(x,t) Q(x,t) & \text{in } (0,L)\times(0,T)\\
> R(x,0) = R_0(x) & \text{for }x \in (0,L)\\
> R(0,t) = G(t) & \text{for }t \in (0,T).
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation}
>   with the supplementary assumptions:
>   \begin{align*}
> & 1. \text{ $R$ is unitary (i.e. $RR^\intercal = R^\intercal R = I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix),}\\
> & 2. \text{ the determinant of $R$ is equal to one,}\\
> & 3. \text{ $P$ and $Q$ are both skew-symmetric (i.e. $Q^\intercal = -Q$ and $P^\intercal = -P$).}\\
> \end{align*}

(Here $\partial_t$ and $\partial_x$ denote the partial derivative with respect to time and space respectively.)

Following ideas from the scalar case (see [Two PDE for one unknown?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3152541/two-pde-for-one-unknown)), I first considered, for $x \in (0, L)$ fixed, the solution to the initial value problem $\partial_t R = R P$:
\begin{align*}
R(x,t) = R_0(x) \exp\left( \int_0^t P(x,s)ds \right),
\end{align*}
and for $t \in (0,T)$ fixed, the solution to the initial value problem $\partial_x R = R Q$:
\begin{align*}
R(x,t) = G(t) \exp \left( \int_0^x Q(y,t) dy \right).
\end{align*}
I was looking for conditions on the coefficients $P$, $Q$ and on the initial and boundary data, sufficient to imply the existence of a solution $R$ (e.g. $G'(t) = G(t) Q(0,t)$, and others). However, the fact that matrices (and not scalars) are involved implies that terms do not necessarily commute (e.g. $R$ and $\partial_t R$ do not necessarily commute).

Any suggestion of method, reference, explanation of why it is/is not possible to have a solution, would be welcome. Thank you.

Edit: I realize now that the formula I gave (above) for the solutions of the initial value problems are probably not correct without assuming that some quantities involving $P(x,t)$ and $Q(x,t)$ commute.